# Returning results from a loop in another excel sheet in the same workbook

Tags: vba, object, range

What am I defining wrong?

I constructed a For Each ..Next loop. I had a function applied to it, and I tried to return the results in a table on a next sheet in my Excel Workbook.
However, I keep on getting the Error 1004, Object or Application Run-Time error whenever I apply this: Note that table 1 is a ReDim table1(Nb_Rows - 1, 6)

```
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2", Range("A2").Offset(Nb_Rows - 1, 6)).Value = Table1
```

However, if I apply THIS code, I get no error. Yet, I cannot use this one because it requires a manual selection. How can I deal with this?

```
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(Nb_Rows -1, 6)).Value = Table1
```

I also tried this way:

```
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(Nb_Rows - 1, 6)).Value = Table1
```

And it didn't work.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And what about:

```
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").Offset(Nb_Rows - 1, 6)).Value = Table1
```

Comment: It's really when I click on the cell and Select it when it works. Somehow I cannot get VBA to select that cell for me :(

Comment: and you select `Range("A2")` in `Sheet2` or you select any other cell?? what is `Nb_Rows`??

Comment: I Changed something a little and it all worked! I specified it as    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2", Worksheet("Sheet2").Range("A2").Offset(Nb_Rows - 1, 6)).Value = Table1 

Thanks for your help!